# Multiple conditions on two column with order by

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
Users (Table1)
---------------------------
id      username    enabled
1       user1           1
2       user2           1
3       user3           1
4       user4           1

Packages (Table2)
---------------------------
id      package_type
1       lead
2       featured

Subscription (Table3)
---------------------------
id      user_id     package_id      enabled
1           1           1               1
2           1           2               1
3           2           1               0  <- user2 don't have lead package active
4           2           2               1
5           3           1               1
6           4           1               1
7           4           2               1
```

Queries to Create tables and insert above data

```
CREATE TABLE `users`( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username` VARCHAR(255), `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ); 
CREATE TABLE `packages`( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `package_type` VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ); 
CREATE TABLE `subscription`( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `package_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, `enabled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`package_id`) REFERENCES `packages`(`id`) ); 

INSERT INTO `packages` (`package_type`) VALUES ('lead') , ('featured'); 
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('user1'), ('user2'), ('user3'), ('user4');
INSERT INTO `subscription` (`user_id`, `package_id`, `enabled`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1'), ('1', '2', '1'), ('2', '1', '0'), ('2', '2', '1'), ('3', '1', '1'), ('4', '1','1'), ('4', '2','1') ;
```

---

I have tested this sample query which need to modify

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  p.package_type,
  u.username,
  u.enabled,
  RAND() AS random
FROM 
  users u
  LEFT JOIN subscription s ON u.id = s.user_id
  LEFT JOIN packages p ON s.package_id = p.id  
WHERE 
  u.enabled = 1 AND s.enabled = 1  
-- GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY p.package_type ASC  , random ASC
```

and output is

```
id  package_type  username  enabled               random
```

---

```
 1  featured      user1           1     0.1285319878985472
 2  featured      user2           1    0.14050112477550388  <- user2 don't have lead package active so should not show up in result
 4  featured      user4           1    0.15676092836704192
 1  lead          user1           1     0.2874740681494345
 3  lead          user3           1     0.3382110375335543
 4  lead          user4           1     0.8286330139531131
```

expected output is

```
id  package_type  username  enabled               random
```

---

```
 1  featured      user1           1     0.1285319878985472
 4  featured      user4           1    0.15676092836704192     
 3  lead          user3           1     0.3382110375335543
```

This output should meet these conditions

1. show only users who have lead package active
2. if user have also featured package then featured users come first in output

Comment: to confirm - its show all packages for users, who have an active lead package, but show featured packages first, if they exist?

Comment: yes it will show all users who have active lead pkgs and if they have also featured package then show them first but user should be only one time not two times with both packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct inner joins for your criteria, `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to show the featured package in result set to sort featured ones first i have used `SUM(p.id = 2)` to sort users that have featured package to show first

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(  
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.package_type ORDER BY p.`id` DESC),',',1
  ) package_type,
  u.username,
  u.enabled
FROM 
  users u
   JOIN subscription s ON u.id = s.user_id
   JOIN packages p ON s.package_id = p.id  
WHERE 
  u.enabled = 1 AND s.enabled = 1
  GROUP BY u.`id`
  HAVING SUM(p.id = 1) > 0
  ORDER BY SUM(p.id = 2) DESC  ,RAND()
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4080/4)

Comment: i have made correction and edited the insert data queries in question please check again with dummy data

Comment: this is heavily reliant on the order of the packages in the packages table

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results you want by taking two queries, and `unioning` the results.

```
select q.user_id, q.package_type, u.username, q.enabled, rand() from (
select 1 as t, s.user_id, p.package_type, s.enabled 
  from subscriptions s
    inner join packages p
      on s.package_id = p.id
  where p.package_type = 'featured'
    and s.enabled = 1
    and exists 
      (select 1
        from subscriptions ss
          inner join packages pp on ss.package_id = pp.id
        where ss.enabled = 1
          and pp.package_type = 'lead'
          and ss.user_id = s.user_id
      )
union all
select 2 as t, s.user_id, p.package_type, s.enabled
  from subscriptions s
    inner join packages p
      on s.package_id = p.id
   where not exists
     (select 1 
       from subscriptions ss
         inner join packages pp on ss.package_id = pp.id
        where ss.enabled = 1
          and pp.package_type = 'featured'
          and ss.user_id = s.user_id
     )
     and p.package_type = 'lead'
     and s.enabled = 1
) q
inner join users u
  on q.user_id = u.id
order by t asc
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01acb/19)

The first query gets all of your users who have an active lead package, and a feature package, and returns their featured packages.

The second query gets all of your users who have an active lead package, and no feature package, and returns their lead packages.

Each query is given an identifier `t` to establish if it is the featured, or lead package result, and we then sort by that.